# iOS Crash on copying an NSArray EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, crash, crashlytics

Here are two stack traces from Crashlytics, both containing the same line of my code, but resulting in two different crashes.

```
# OS Version: 10.3.2 (14F90)
# Device: iPad 5
# RAM Free: 3.8%
# Disk Free: 90.7%

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x18d365090 _platform_memset + 126
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18d2ebd00 _nano_malloc_check_clear + 584
2  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18d2eacb0 nano_calloc + 80
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18d2dc4e8 malloc_zone_calloc + 168
4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18d2dc41c calloc + 40
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18cd18160 class_createInstance + 76
6  CoreFoundation                 0x18e2b2928 __CFAllocateObject + 28
7  CoreFoundation                 0x18e29c064 +[__NSSingleObjectArrayI __new::] + 28
8  CoreFoundation                 0x18e18cd18 -[NSArray initWithArray:range:copyItems:] + 400
9  MyApp                          0x10010003c -[ConstituentDownload currentProgress] (ConstituentDownload.m:117)
10 MyApp                          0x1001000b4 -[ConstituentDownload currentProgress] (ConstituentDownload.m:118)
11 MyApp                          0x1001000b4 -[ConstituentDownload currentProgress] (ConstituentDownload.m:118)
12 MyApp                          0x1001000b4 -[ConstituentDownload currentProgress] (ConstituentDownload.m:118)
13 MyApp                          0x1001000b4 -[ConstituentDownload currentProgress] (ConstituentDownload.m:118)
14 MyApp                          0x1001000b4 -[ConstituentDownload currentProgress] (ConstituentDownload.m:118)
15 MyApp                          0x1001000b4 -[ConstituentDownload currentProgress] (ConstituentDownload.m:118)
16 MyApp                          0x1001000b4 -[ConstituentDownload currentProgress] (ConstituentDownload.m:118)
17 MyApp                          0x1001000b4 -[ConstituentDownload currentProgress] (ConstituentDownload.m:118)
18 MyApp                          0x1001000b4 -[ConstituentDownload currentProgress] (ConstituentDownload.m:118)
19 MyApp                          0x1001000b4 -[ConstituentDownload currentProgress] (ConstituentDownload.m:118)
20 MyApp                          0x100100234 -[ConstituentDownload sendProgressNotification] (ConstituentDownload.m:141)
... button press stuff...
```

and:

```
# OS Version: 10.3.1 (14E304)
# Device: iPad 4
# RAM Free: 4.7%
# Disk Free: 12.2%

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1bc38692 objc_retain + 1
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1c8acf39 +[__NSArrayI __new:::] + 74
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1c8ae9f1 -[__NSArrayM copyWithZone:] + 174
3  MyApp                          0x189407 -[ConstituentDownload currentProgress] (ConstituentDownload.m:117)
4  MyApp                          0x18999f -[ConstituentDownload userInfoForProgressNotification] (ConstituentDownload.m:180)
5  MyApp                          0x189611 -[ConstituentDownload sendProgressNotification] (ConstituentDownload.m:144)
...button press stuff...
```

And here is the method that causes the crash:

```
- (float)currentProgress {

    float sections = [self.childDownloads count] + 1;
    float referencedProgress = 0.;
    // This line causes the crash - where we copy the property array
    for(ConstituentDownload *d in [self.childDownloads copy]) {
        referencedProgress += d.currentProgress;
    }
    float progress = (super.currentProgress + referencedProgress) / sections;
    return progress;
}
```

The `self.childDownloads` is a NSMutableArray containing objects of the same type that this method lives in: the `ConstituentDownload`. It is accessed from other threads and can have elements added to it, which is why I copy it first before iterating over it. This array tends to contain 0-20 objects in it.

Could this crash be caused by mutating the array in a different thread, even though I'm copying it here?

Could it be caused by some kind of memory corruption? If so, can you point me in the right direction for figuring that out?

Could it be caused by running out of RAM on the device? If so, why wouldn't this have been reported as an out-of-memory error instead of generating a crash report?

Yes, this method is recursive, in a sense. The parent `ConstituentDownload` calls `currentProgress` on each of its child downloads, who in turn call it on each of their child downloads. The crash stack sometimes has only 1 recursive call in it, and sometimes around 10 or so, as seen in these two crash stacks.

This crash has only been seen on devices running iOS 9 and iOS 10, but that's probably because almost all of my users are on those two OS versions.

What does KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE mean anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a specific reference that states it precisely, but I think you should assume that it is not safe to copy a mutable array this way.

Generally speaking, it is not safe to iterate over an `NSMutableArray` in one thread, while it is being mutated from another thread. Whatever way `copy` is implemented under the hood, it must iterate over the array in some fashion to do its job.

From your description, it sounds like you might be adding/removing items from multiple different threads. Are you using some sort of locking or serialization to make that thread-safe? If not, that could also cause the crash to occur at this point.

And if you are, you should use that same locking to protect this `copy` operation.